# Pattern for unit testing async queue that calls main queue on completion

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, sentestingkit

This is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816159/dispatch-sync-on-main-queue-hangs-in-unit-test), but different enough that I figured I'd throw it into a new one.  I have some code that runs async on a custom queue, then executes a completion block on the main thread when complete.  I'd like to write unit test around this method.  My method on `MyObject` looks like this.

```
+ (void)doSomethingAsyncThenRunCompletionBlockOnMainQueue:(void (^)())completionBlock {

    dispatch_queue_t customQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myObject.myCustomQueue", 0);

    dispatch_async(customQueue, ^(void) {

        dispatch_queue_t currentQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
        dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

        if (currentQueue == mainQueue) {
            NSLog(@"already on main thread");
            completionBlock();
        } else {
            dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) {
                NSLog(@"NOT already on main thread");
                completionBlock();
        }); 
    }
});
```

}

I threw in the main queue test for extra safety, but It always hits the `dispatch_async`.  My unit test looks like the following.

```
- (void)testDoSomething {

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    void (^completionBlock)(void) = ^(void){        
        NSLog(@"Completion Block!");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }; 

    [MyObject doSomethingAsyncThenRunCompletionBlockOnMainQueue:completionBlock];

    // Wait for async code to finish
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);

    STFail(@"I know this will fail, thanks");
}
```

I create a semaphore in order to block the test from finishing before the async code does.  This would work great if I don't require the completion block to run on the main thread.  However, as a couple folks pointed out in the question I linked to above, the fact that the test is running on the main thread and then I enqueue the completion block on the main thread means I'll just hang forever.

Calling the main queue from an async queue is a pattern I see a lot for updating the UI and such.  Does anyone have a better pattern for testing async code that calls back to the main queue?

Comment: I've collected a few resources regarding async testing, including BJ Homer's answer, in a blog post.

http://drewsmitscode.posterous.com/testing-asynchronous-code-in-objective-c

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are two ways to get blocks dispatched to the main queue to run. The first is via `dispatch_main`, as mentioned by Drewsmits. However, as he also noted, there's a big problem with using `dispatch_main` in your test: **it never returns**. It will just sit there waiting to run any blocks that come its way for the rest of eternity. That's not so helpful for a unit test, as you can imagine.

Luckily, there's another option. In the `COMPATIBILITY` section of the [`dispatch_main` man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_main.3.html), it says this:

> Cocoa applications need not call dispatch_main().  Blocks submitted to
>   the main queue will be executed as part of the "common modes" of the
>   application's main NSRunLoop or CFRunLoop.

In other words, if you're in a Cocoa app, the dispatch queue is drained by the main thread's `NSRunLoop`. So all we need to do is keep the run loop running while we're waiting for the test to finish. It looks like this:

```
- (void)testDoSomething {

    __block BOOL hasCalledBack = NO;

    void (^completionBlock)(void) = ^(void){        
        NSLog(@"Completion Block!");
        hasCalledBack = YES;
    }; 

    [MyObject doSomethingAsyncThenRunCompletionBlockOnMainQueue:completionBlock];

    // Repeatedly process events in the run loop until we see the callback run.

    // This code will wait for up to 10 seconds for something to come through
    // on the main queue before it times out. If your tests need longer than
    // that, bump up the time limit. Giving it a timeout like this means your
    // tests won't hang indefinitely. 

    // -[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:] always processes exactly one event or
    // returns after timing out. 

    NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    while (hasCalledBack == NO && [loopUntil timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:loopUntil];
    }

    if (!hasCalledBack)
    {
        STFail(@"I know this will fail, thanks");
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again, thanks for taking the time to answer!  This looks like a pretty good pattern for OCUnit async testing.

Comment: amongst my google searches, this was by far the best and easiest to implement solution for asynchronous testing that i found.

Comment: You should check that hasCalledBack == NO before failing right? Or is that while() loop supposed to return somehow when if works.

Comment: Yeah, you'd want to change that. I just copied that directly from the OP's post.

Comment: I was working with another developer trying to figure out how to do this and completely forgot about calling the runloop directly. Awesome answer.

Comment: This code assumes that I can pass a completion block to the code I am testing. I am not sure if I consider this as a viable approach at all.

Comment: Historical note: SenTest has been replaced by XCTest, which now includes support for asynchronous tests directly via the `XCTestExpectation` API.

Answer (score 18):

An alternate method, using semaphores and runloop churning. Note that dispatch_semaphore_wait returns nonzero if it times out.

```
- (void)testFetchSources
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [MyObject doSomethingAsynchronousWhenDone:^(BOOL success) {
        STAssertTrue(success, @"Failed to do the thing!");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];

    dispatch_release(semaphore);
}
```

Comment: Your nsrunloop addition was quite helpful!

Answer (score 7):

Square included a clever addition to SenTestCase in their SocketRocket project that makes this easy. You can call it like this:

```
[self runCurrentRunLoopUntilTestPasses:^BOOL{
    return [someOperation isDone];
} timeout: 60 * 60];
```

The code is available here:

[SenTestCase+SRTAdditions.h](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SRWebSocketTests/SenTestCase+SRTAdditions.h)

[SenTestCase+SRTAdditions.m](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SRWebSocketTests/SenTestCase%2BSRTAdditions.m)

Answer (score 7):

BJ Homer's solution is the best solution so far. I've created some macro's built on that solution.

Check out the project here https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper

```
- (void)testDoSomething {

    __block BOOL somethingIsDone = NO;

    void (^completionBlock)(void) = ^(void){        
        NSLog(@"Completion Block!");
        somethingIsDone = YES;
    }; 

    [MyObject doSomethingAsyncThenRunCompletionBlockOnMainQueue:completionBlock];

    WAIT_WHILE(!somethingIsDone, 1.0); 
    NSLog(@"This won't be reached until async job is done");
}
```

The `WAIT_WHILE(expressionIsTrue, seconds)`-macro will evaluate the input until the expression is not true or the time limit is reached. I think it is hard to get it cleaner than this

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to execute blocks on the main queue is to call [`dispatch_main()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW12) from the main thread.  However, as far as I can see from the docs, that will never return, so you can never tell if your test has failed.

Another approach is to make your unit test go into its [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001441-CH201-F17705) after the dispatch.  Then the  completion block will have a chance to execute and you also have the opportunity for the run loop to time out, after which you can deem the test failed if the completion block has not run.

Answer (score 2):

Based on several of the other answers to this question, I set this up for convenience (and fun): https://github.com/kallewoof/UTAsync

Hope it helps someone.