# Accept header NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I can not set the header for a connection with NSXMLParser.

in particular I should put this header:

**"Accept Application/xml"**

this is my code:

```
func parse (handler: () -> Void) {
     self.handler = handler

     dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {


         newLink NSURL var = (string: SomeStructure.newLink)
         UIApplication.sharedApplication (). NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
         let xmlCode = NSData (contentsOfURL: newLink!)
         UIApplication.sharedApplication (). NetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
         // let resulset = NSString (date: xmlCode, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
         // println (resulset)
         let parser = NSXMLParser (date: xmlCode)
         parser.delegate = self

         if! Parser.parse () {
             self.delegate? .XMLParserError (self, error: "Error Parser Category.")
             println ("Parser error")
         }
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `NSMutableURLRequest` instead. `NSData` doesn't provide http headers.

Comment: Can you get me an example please ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24176452/623396