# Image not loading in UIWebview

Tags: ios, json, uiwebview

i am getting a "text" from mysql database using web api and Json data i show the text in a uiwebview to  ba able to use the links and show image, but the image are not showning:

this text is a snippet of the json text :

```
 <p style=\"text-align: center;\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://sofabold.dk/images/blog/Placeringsaendring2014.jpg\" style=\"border-style:solid; border-width:2px; height:852px; width:321px\" /></p>
```

and i do this in object c :

```
        NSString *blogText =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [blogInfo mutableArrayValueForKey:@"indhold"]];

        NSLog(@"%@",blogText);

        NSString *newBlogText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",blogText];

        // Set op the text in webview.

        NSString *newBlogText1 = [newBlogText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\n" withString: @""];

        NSString *newBlogText2 = [newBlogText1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
        NSString *newBlogText3 = [newBlogText2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
        NSString *newBlogText4 = [newBlogText3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];


        NSString *stripedAll = [newBlogText4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"</script>" withString: @"Dette kan desværre ikke ses på dette media, besøg venligst www.sofabold.dk"];


        // NSLog(@"%@",stripedAll);

        NSString *headLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[blogInfo mutableArrayValueForKey:@"subject"]];

        headLineString = [headLine decodeHTMLEntities ];


        NSString *cssString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><style type='text/css\'> body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #000000; font-size:14px;text-align:justify} .class1 { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica-BoldOblique; color: #000000; font-size:18px;text-align:center }  </style> <body> <p class='class1'> %@ </p></body></html>",headLineString];




        NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ <br /><br />%@ %@", cssString, stripedAll,_blogForfatter, _blogTime];

        [detailText loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

but  it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

iv been trying for days on google and trying different things but can make it work.

it looks like uiwebview user the alt tag instead og src ..... any one know how to fix that

htlmstring:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLConnection Using iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176362/nsurlconnection-using-ios-swift)

Comment: post the html loading into web view

Comment: the html ?  its  txt with html tags  i get from the server in json

Comment: NSLog(htmlString);  This is what @Vinodh is asking ... show this.

Comment: if i post it as edit  all html tags gets striped  so made a screen  se edit

Comment: @Skovie the first line of image states that you are not providing source and img tag is not closed properly

Comment: can you help close it ? :-D