# Get a content of webpage after javascript is loaded SWIFT

Tags: javascript, html, swift, ios8, xcode6

How can I get a content of a webpage with the url, after the javascript has been loaded to the html?

I tried
`let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myurl.com/")
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)`
but its showing only the source of the html page, because the javascript not loaded yet

Comment: have you used webview ?

Comment: Yes but I didn't manage on how to get the webview as a html string

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection has a delegate: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, which offers the function `connectionDidFinishLoading`
Check [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading:) for more information. 
A similar request has been answered here: [NSURLConnection Using iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176362/nsurlconnection-using-ios-swift)