# iOS application quit due to slow net connection

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.1

I am working on iOS application in swift. I need to parse two web api(XML) at application launch time and during this period, I need to show launch screen. So I sent a synchronous request to parse the data from server.
If net connection is good then application working fine but due to slow net connection or it takes more then 20 seconds to load data from server it can quit automatic.
How to fix this issue. Please suggest it.

Comment: Use an *asynchronous* request. // Your app quits because a synchronous request blocks the main thread, and if it goes for too long then iOS kills the app.

Comment: Just call your api in application's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in appdelegate.

Comment: Any other option to show launch screen with asynchronous request.

Comment: I have already parsed data in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: You can add delay functions like sleep(20.0) in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. But this is not a good way to do this. If you are calling a asynchronous method you should do it properly by try-catch and reload view once api call returns data.

Comment: @vipulk617 No, `sleep` will only block the main thread for a given time, thus *also* blocking your connection and your app. **Never** use this to attempt to delay a result.

Comment: downvoted - 1000th times discussed on SO & really bad idea

Comment: Use some proper asyncrhonous request. The cocoa framework is quite helpful here. Do NOT use any sleep() calls.

Comment: @Eric D for helping me.

Comment: See this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176362/nsurlconnection-using-ios-swift

Comment: @HermannKlecker thanks for giving valuable time for me.

Comment: @SaqibOmer NO - NEVER sleep on the main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never send synchronous requests in main thread!

Add new VC on load. There you can load your data async. When data is ready, pass it the next VC.