# How to call webAPI?I had created my SIGNUP page but i don't known how to call webapi in button click event

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

I had created my SIGNUP page but i don't known how to call webapi in button click event IOS SWIFT.`**`enter code here`**`

Comment: I am asking swift...

Comment: you can use Alamofire. Its great library in its self.

Comment: oh t q ..it is very useful for me...

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to call the WebApi. 
 1. NSURLConnection
 2. NSURLSession

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176452/2010154 for NSURLConnection

http://www.kaleidosblog.com/nsurlsession-in-swift-get-and-post-data for the NSURLSession

Comment: When you want to call any webAPI in the iOS application. If you would like to write your own code by using apple's frameworks, Otherwise there are 3rd party frameworks for calling the web API like Alamofire.