# Swift Google Calendar Account Signout

Tags: ios, swift, google-calendar-api

I just started to learn Swift recently and I implemented the sample code that Google gives us to create a calendar. However, I would also like to know how to signout of an account to switch to another calendar but I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone give me some pointers?

Thanks for your help in advance! :-)

Tim

Comment: could u help me google calendar swift @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Google docs has a [revoking a token guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) for OAuth 2.0.

You can use request using HTTP/REST:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

If you're not familiar with HTTP request in Swift, try the following guides in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176362/nsurlconnection-using-ios-swift) using [NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift).

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: would this work with the sample code google gives us? I didn't use any NSURL in my code before :o

Comment: You'll never know if you don't try.