# Xcode Playground with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground

I'm trying to import cocoapods into an Xcode playground in my project but despite finding some solutions, none seem to work in Xcode 7.3.1.

For example I've tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36047766/2570590) but I get an error at the import in the playground:

> "No such module"

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying](https://github.com/neonichu/ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying) or add this to your Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this solution is mentioned in the post I referenced in my question and does not work in Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Try to build all the pods scheme before your.