# Adding cocoapod to Swift Playground without Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode9, swift-playground

I want to add a cocoapod to Swift Playground but I tried to run the `pod init` but I'm getting this error:

`[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one`

I tried the solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367609/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-playground)

1. `gem install cocoapods-playgrounds`
2. `pod playgrounds Alamofire`

But I'm getting this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source/Playground with Platform Choice.xctemplate
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/generate.rb:43:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/generate.rb:43:in `foreach'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/generate.rb:43:in `dir_for_platform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/generate.rb:10:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/workspace.rb:26:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/workspace.rb:26:in `block in generate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/workspace.rb:23:in `chdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/workspace.rb:23:in `generate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-playgrounds-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-playgrounds/command/playgrounds.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Any of you knows a work around this error?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367609/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-playground

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use cocoapods with playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367609/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-playground)

Comment: Update ruby and then update gem `cocoapods-playgrounds`.

Comment: @PranavKasetti there's a year old comment under that thread saying that framework doesn't work with Xcode9 and its git repo has also been archived, so have you actually tested it with Xcode9 and did it work for you?

Comment: Ah, didn't check that. That would explain a lot! In that case I recommend you post an answer to get some credit. :)

Comment: @PranavKasetti, I updated ruby and the gem and didn't work .

Comment: If the need is to quickly test the Cocoapod, many times using the provided github example/demo project for the Cocoapod is a quick starting point to try out the pod.

Comment: @Marcy, can you post and example

Comment: Absolutely. Alamofire was mentioned so if you look at their Github site at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire there is a folder called "Example" which contains a project called "iOS Example" for creating a demo app using Alamofire. Some Cocoapods call the folder Demo. Sometimes they include projects for iOS, MacOS or both.

Comment: @Marcy that's still way more complicated and time consuming than using a Playground. Have a look at [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), who actually provide a Playground with an embedded framework if you download the framework directly from their website instead of using CocoaPods/Carthage to install it. This enables much faster testing than having to build and run a complete app all the time you want to test some little things with a framework.