# dispatch queue concurrent not work as except in swift

Tags: swift, concurrency

I think that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` will work random, but it seem to work in order.

Is there's something wrong with my code?

**code**

```
let concurrentDispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("serialDispatchQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
func foo(name: String, queue: dispatch_queue_t) {
    for i in 1...10 {
        dispatch_sync(queue) { () -> Void in
            let r = Double(random() % 10)
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.02 * r)
            print("\(name) \(i)")
        }
    }
}
foo("concurrent", queue: concurrentDispatchQueue)
```

**output**

```
concurrent 1
concurrent 2
concurrent 3
concurrent 4
concurrent 5
concurrent 6
concurrent 7
concurrent 8
concurrent 9
concurrent 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dispatching *synchronously* to the queue.
Each

```
dispatch_sync(queue) { ... }
```

returns only *after* the closure has been executed. To test
concurrent execution on a queue, change the call to

```
dispatch_async(queue) { ... }
```

Note that you have to add

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

if you are testing it in a Playground, see for example
[How do I run Asynchronous callbacks in Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for newbee question!