# View GET request results in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, rest, alamofire, swift-playground

We're trying to test an Alomofire GET request using a Playground.  It's working but we can't see the JSON returned by the request in the Playground.  How can you do this?   Note clicking the right arrows in the screen shot doesn't show any JSON.

Playground:

[image]

The [request's](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2) JSON response:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 2,
  "title": "qui est esse",
  "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33536290/4096655

Comment: You're right.  Thanks.  I voted to close it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your playground ended before the request could complete. Pause it indefinitely by setting `needsIndefiniteExecution = true`:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import XCPlayground

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2")
    .responseJSON { response in
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        print(json)
    }

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Thanks.  I believe this API has changed per stackoverflow.com/a/33536290/4096655 - which worked.  Thanks for the help.