# XCode playground hangs on async code

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire, swift-playground

I'm trying to make an async request inside XCode 7.3 playground, using Alamofire. I've included two additional statements - `needsIndefiniteExecution = true` and `finishExecution()` as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33536290/603268.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

print("Before request")

Alamofire
    .request(.GET, "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .responseString { res in
        print(res)
        XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
    }
    //.resume() - adding this did not help
```

I've also set the playground execution mode to manual.

The first time, everything works fine, the response is printed and the playground finishes execution.

However, if I run it second time, it hangs and does not print any output (even no "Begin request"). I have to restart XCode to make it work again.

Comment: How do you run it a second time?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove:

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
```

Comment: Yeah, it solves the issue with consecutive runs, but it has its drawbacks too - it either keeps playground running for ~30 seconds or I have to manually stop it (as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24066317/603268). I was hoping for a cleaner solution