# NSOperation mainQueue is not getting executed

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

```
class AsyncOperation : NSOperation {
    override func main () {
        print("In the user queue")
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            print("main block")
        })
    }
}
let queue = NSOperationQueue()
let operation = AsyncOperation();
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

it prints `In the user queue` but does not print `main block` . Since I am adding to the main queue I expect it to get executed. Do i have to start the queue execution ??

Comment: I assume that this is a command-line program, and adding `dispatch_main()` should solve your problem, as explained in the linked-to thread. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Yes I was trying it in playground. dispatch_main() worked. Thanks

Comment: For playgrounds (and you might have mentioned that) there is also another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground: `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`