# Difference between dispatching to a queue with `sync` and using a work item with a `.wait` flag?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, swift3

I'm learning about Apple's GCD, and watching the video [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/).

At 16:00 in this video, a flag for `DispatchWorkItem` is described called `.wait`, and the functionality and diagram both show exactly what I thought `myQueue.sync(execute:)` was for.

[image: .wait diagram]

So, my question is; what is the difference between:

```
myQueue.sync { sleep(1); print("sync") }
```

And:

```
myQueue.async(flags: .wait) { sleep(1); print("wait") }
// NOTE: This syntax doesn't compile, I'm not sure where the `.wait` flag moved to.
// `.wait` Seems not to be in the DispatchWorkItemFlags enum.
```

Seems like both approaches block the current thread while they wait for the named queue to:

1. Finish any current or prior work (if serial)
2. Complete the given block/work item

My understanding of this must be off somewhere, what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.wait` is *not* a flag in `DispatchWorkItemFlags`, and that is why
your code

```
myQueue.async(flags: .wait) { sleep(1); print("wait") }
```

does not compile.

[`wait()` is a method of `DispatchWorkItem`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Dispatch/Block.swift#L59) and just a wrapper for 
[`dispatch_block_wait()`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/dispatch/block.h#L278).

```
/*!
 * @function dispatch_block_wait
 *
 * @abstract
 * Wait synchronously until execution of the specified dispatch block object has
 * completed or until the specified timeout has elapsed.
```

Simple example:

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.queue", attributes: .concurrent)
let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
    sleep(1)
    print("done")
}
myQueue.async(execute: workItem)
print("before waiting")
workItem.wait()
print("after waiting")

dispatchMain()
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it gives you a little more granularity of control than `sync` then. What is `dispatchMain()` doing?

Comment: @SimplGy: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452860-dispatch_main. You need in in programs without a runloop (such as command-line programs) to keep GCD running. In a Playground you achieve the same effect (I think) with `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you! A small question: what if the code inside the `workItem` block is asynchronous? For example the `SKTextureAtlas`'s `preload(completionHandler:)`. How can we ensure that the `workItem` will wait for that code to finish and only then mark itself as completed?

Comment: @damirstuhec: A DispatchGroup might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR Not sure if `DispatchGroup` is what I need. Isn't the `DispatchGroup` for grouping the `DispatchQueue`'s to get notified when they are all done with the tasks in their queues? I'm just looking for a way to have a async block of code executed inside of the `DispatchWorkItem` which should wait for it to be finished.

Comment: @MartinR Also, `DispatchGroup` is iOS 10 only.

Comment: @damirstuhec: No, DispatchGroup is Swift 3. It is dispatch_group_t in Swift 1+2.

Comment: @MartinR True, but that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @damirstuhec: I would suggest that you ask a new question for your problem, this should not be handled in comments.