# Is it necessary to circumvent App Transport Security from an XCode Playground?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

In Swift, I understand how to circumvent App Transport Security from 'app code' (using Info.plist), but having gone through the efforts of setting up Playgrounds properly (within a Workspace and with working CocoaPod dependencies) so that I can use them to develop/test API integrations, I'm suddenly wondering if I also need to circumvent ATS during this development, or whether - as Playgrounds are inherently development code - Playgrounds work happily with standard http?

Comment: Can't you just test it?

Comment: @Kametrixom Testing it, and further googling, proved inconclusive. However, I now suspect that ATS is not required (nor configurable) for Playgrounds. It seems the problem I was facing wasn't to do with ATS but rather to do with Playgrounds being executed continually. Therefore, network responses are never received. If network responses are crucial to your Playground development, the solution is to `import XCPlayground` etc., as described at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground>