# Create delay in a block of code in swift 3

Tags: swift

The following code doesn't print hello after the delay.

Anything wrong ?

```
 func delay(seconds delay:Int, closure:@escaping ()->()) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(delay)) {
        closure()
    }
}

delay(seconds: 5) { 
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: I would try to do it in Xcode, instead of playground. Also, print something in between the lines, to investigate what parts of the functions are running. Besides, Xcode is a little better in telling you what's happening,as opposed to playground.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run Asynchronous callbacks in Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating a runloop, otherwise the program just exit without calling the asynchronous block. You shouldn't need this if you are developing for iOS app.

```
var keepAlive = true

   func delay(seconds delay:Int, closure:@escaping ()->()) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(delay)) {
        closure()
        }
    }


   delay(seconds: 5) { 
        print("hello")
        keepAlive = false
    }

let runLoop = RunLoop.current
while keepAlive && runLoop.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1)) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let delayInSeconds = 5.0

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {

print("hello")

}
```

Comment: You can run this in the playground, hello will still not get printed.

Comment: If you are running this in a Playground, you have to include the following two lines: `import PlaygroundSupport` and 
`PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Comment: thanks, it works. How about running it outside of playground?

Comment: Hey I tell here the basic concept. If you help this then mark as best

Comment: why I get -1? I think this code is fine. The playground support not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Alwin I do not know as well :) my answer got the same -2 without comments

Comment: @J.Doe this make me unhappy