# Playground - DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, dispatch-queue

I am running the following in **Playground**, but nothing is getting printed :

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(1)) {
    print("hiii")
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, to make it wait for your async thread:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```