# How to debug JSONDecoder when no errors show?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, jsondecoder

I'm building a Swift app and testing in an Xcode Playground.  Calling the NYTimes Search API and trying to store its response in a struct. The code executes cleanly and no errors appear (I am using a do, try, catch), but I cannot print any properties from the resulting object (`print(json.status)`).

My hunch is that something is fishy with this line but I'm not sure what since no errors are printing from the catch statement

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
```

Form the URL endpoint to make the API call:

```
func APICall() {
        
        let APIKey = "MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE_BUT_IT'S_A_SECRET"
        let searchTerm = "A Super Bowl Sideshow: See the Ageless Man!"
        
        // Remove the spaces and convert them to percents
        guard let encodedSearchTerm = searchTerm.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) 
           else {
              print("Error encoding search term in URL")
              return
        }
    
        let url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=" + encodedSearchTerm + "&api-key=" + APIKey

        getData(from: url)
}
```

Data Task:

```
func getData(from url: String) {
    
    //I believe something is wrong with the following line but I'm not sure what it is
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Error loading data")
            return
        }
        
        var result: NYTSearchResponse?
        
        do {
            
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(NYTSearchResponse.self, from: data)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        guard let json = result else {
            print("Error assigning result to json")
            return
        }
        
        //Try to print these from the resulting object but these commands do not print
        print(json.status)
        print(json.response.docs[0].abstract)
    })
    
    task.resume()
}
```

My NYTSearchResponse struct which mirrors the NYT API JSON response. It's pretty complicated, but I pasted the json response into https://app.quicktype.io/ to build the struct.

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct NYTSearchResponse: Codable {
    let status, copyright: String
    let response: Response
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let docs: [Doc]
    let meta: Meta
}

// MARK: - Doc
struct Doc: Codable {
    let abstract: String
    let webURL: String
    let snippet, leadParagraph, printSection, printPage: String
    let source: String
    let multimedia: [Multimedia]
    let headline: Headline
    let keywords: [Keyword]
    let pubDate: Date
    let documentType, newsDesk, sectionName, subsectionName: String
    let byline: Byline
    let typeOfMaterial, id: String
    let wordCount: Int
    let uri: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case abstract
        case webURL = "web_url"
        case snippet
        case leadParagraph = "lead_paragraph"
        case printSection = "print_section"
        case printPage = "print_page"
        case source, multimedia, headline, keywords
        case pubDate = "pub_date"
        case documentType = "document_type"
        case newsDesk = "news_desk"
        case sectionName = "section_name"
        case subsectionName = "subsection_name"
        case byline
        case typeOfMaterial = "type_of_material"
        case id = "_id"
        case wordCount = "word_count"
        case uri
    }
}

// MARK: - Byline
struct Byline: Codable {
    let original: String
    let person: [Person]
    let organization: String?
}

// MARK: - Person
struct Person: Codable {
    let firstname: String
    let middlename: String?
    let lastname: String
    let qualifier, title: String?
    let role, organization: String
    let rank: Int
}

// MARK: - Headline
struct Headline: Codable {
    let main: String
    let kicker, contentKicker: String?
    let printHeadline: String
    let name, seo, sub: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case main, kicker
        case contentKicker = "content_kicker"
        case printHeadline = "print_headline"
        case name, seo, sub
    }
}

// MARK: - Keyword
struct Keyword: Codable {
    let name, value: String
    let rank: Int
    let major: String
}

// MARK: - Multimedia
struct Multimedia: Codable {
    let rank: Int
    let subtype: String
    let caption, credit: String?
    let type, url: String
    let height, width: Int
    let legacy: Legacy
    let subType, cropName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rank, subtype, caption, credit, type, url, height, width, legacy, subType
        case cropName = "crop_name"
    }
}

// MARK: - Legacy
struct Legacy: Codable {
    let xlarge: String?
    let xlargewidth, xlargeheight: Int?
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let hits, offset, time: Int
}
```

Comment: So what actually prints?

Comment: Also how do you know you are not printing empty strings? Why not print `json` itself and actually see what you’ve got? Or even use the debugger?

Comment: @matt Nothing prints! Just tried to print(json).

Comment: Also I'm using a playground in Xcode. When I print(url) in the APICall(), the url string shows to the right of the screen, but print(json) in getData() doesn't show any preview on the right column

Comment: Try using a non playground. Playgrounds are not good for this sort of thing.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the advice. It was totally the playground.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058336/how-do-i-run-asynchronous-callbacks-in-playground for some ideas on how to make waiting for asynchronous requests in playgrounds work.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the code out of the playground and it works.

Comment: The trouble is that the original question never mentioned the playground.

Comment: Apologies, I'm pretty new to coding and very new to Xcode and StackOverflow. Will get better at everything!

Comment: OK but what I'm suggesting is: let's edit the question to make the playground part of it. That will make this question-and-answer _useful_ to people. Otherwise this is just your personal blog about your personal adventures in programming, which is not a correct use of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand. Made an edit to mention use of the playground in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, now we're cooking. :) Maybe the playground could have been made to work by making it live longer; the problem here is that your code is asynchronous so the playground just stops before we reach the end of the code. But really it is better to develop in a real project, where you get the benefit of the debugger and other forms of sanity. Playgrounds are just for play.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a ton for the tips and pointers.