# datatask not executed, request is null

Tags: swift, api, nsurlsessiondatatask

```
import Foundation

let headers = [
    "x-rapidapi-key": "myKey",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com"
]

let urlR = URL(string: "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?i=tt4154796&r=json")

var request = URLRequest(url: urlR!)

request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print(data ?? "data")
    print(response ?? "response")
    print(error ?? "error")
}

dataTask.resume()
```

The code inside datatask is not executed and even if i check with debugger and breakpoint, it would be skipped. Someone know why?

Comment: "if i check with debugger and breakpoint, it would be skipped." => Asynchronous

Comment: You need to find out how to deal with optional values at first.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code

Comment: `Asynchronous` thread will execute after response will get and it will not stop the other task process. as you mention here break point would be skip. so put brakepoint  at print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, and there's an easy way to prove it: unit tests !

```
import XCTest
class DataTaskTests: XCTestCase {
    var dataTask: URLSessionTask!
    func testDataTask() throws {
        let headers = [
            "x-rapidapi-key": "myKey",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com"
        ]

        let urlR = URL(string: "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/?i=tt4154796&r=json")

        var request = URLRequest(url: urlR!)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let expectation = expectation(description: "testDataTask")
        dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        dataTask.resume()
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 30.0)
    }
}
```

Saying :

> The code inside datatask is not executed

Makes me think that maybe you were trying this code in a [playground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24058336/1425697)

Comment: Ok i set my test and it worked. Now i'm asking why my print are bypassed?

Comment: Are you testing in a playground ?

Comment: well then, with the details you provided all I can say is that your code works and the call back **is** executed. And btw, you can use Xcode and run a playground

Comment: how could I know, the snippet you posted do not compile outside of a playground, but you're telling me that you did not use one. Maybe there's something else in the code you **didn't** share. But if you're asking people what's wrong with the code you posted, the answer is short **nothing**