# How to count number of alive threads in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I want to get the number of threads which are 'alive' in my iOS application.

Can I use `threadDictionary` in the `NSThread` class? Or can I use `mach/thread_info.h`?

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: Stale as soon as returned.

Comment: @MartinR Why do you need to know, why does he need this information for? ;-)

Comment: @Lukasz: Because it could have been an ["XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :)

Comment: @MartinR OK, but his question is clear and even if it is XY something - it does not matter - because solution exists and can still be useful to others (like me, if it was few weeks ago ;-)

Comment: @Lukasz: I did not say that the question is unclear or bad. I just left a comment asking why (s)he needs the information, that's all. I can see no problem with that.

Comment: This is useful if you want to know if you are the only thread in the process. That never goes stale once True until you spawn more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michael Dautermann already answered the question, but this is an example to get threads count using Mach API.
**Note** that its work only on simulator (tested with iOS 6.1), running it on device will fail because `task_for_pid` return `KERN_FAILURE`.

```
/**
 * @return -1 on error, else the number of threads for the current process
 */
static int getThreadsCount()
{
    thread_array_t threadList;
    mach_msg_type_number_t threadCount;
    task_t task;

    kern_return_t kernReturn = task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), getpid(), &task);
    if (kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    kernReturn = task_threads(task, &threadList, &threadCount);
    if (kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }
    vm_deallocate (mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)threadList, threadCount * sizeof(thread_act_t));

    return threadCount;
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way I can get this results on the device except Michael Dautermann's suggestion?

Comment: No, i don't think so, and it does not surprise me. Even if Apple lets the function `task_for_pid` to give one result, I do not think that it will be validated for AppStore.

Comment: It works on my devices. I checked on iOS 6.0 iPod and iOS 7.0 iPad.

Comment: Jailbroken devices ?? It failed on my iPod Touch iOS 6.15, and my iPad iOS 5.0.1

Comment: No. Both the devices are not Jailbroken.

Comment: Strange that work for you on iOS 6.0 and not for me on iOS 6.15 ?

Answer (score 6):

This one works on the device as well:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
// ...
thread_act_array_t threads;
mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count = 0;

const task_t    this_task = mach_task_self();
const thread_t  this_thread = mach_thread_self();

// 1. Get a list of all threads (with count):
kern_return_t kr = task_threads(this_task, &threads, &thread_count);

if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("error getting threads: %s", mach_error_string(kr));
    return NO;
}

mach_port_deallocate(this_task, this_thread);
vm_deallocate(this_task, (vm_address_t)threads, sizeof(thread_t) * thread_count);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the mach_thread_self() and mach_port_deallocate() calls? They are only used by each other and the type returned by mach_thread_self() does not match the type of the argument it is passed as into mach_port_deallocate().  The code "works" without them.  Is something being leaked? Why? Based on what references?  https://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_port_deallocate.html & https://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_thread_self.html are what I read.

Answer (score 3):

["`threadDictionary`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/threadDictionary) is information about a *specific* NSThread.  It's not the total number of threads.

If you want to keep track of "`NSThread`" objects you've created, you'll probably need to create your own NSMutableArray and add new NSThread objects to it and make certain the objects are valid and correct (i.e. threads are executing, threads are finished or cancelled, etc.) each time you want to do a count of your NSThreads.

This likely still would not give you exactly what you want because NSThread isn't the same thing as [threads created and/or references via Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905192/iphone-grand-central-dispatch-main-thread) or other kinds of threads (e.g. pthreads).