# No Response during web service call

Tags: ios, web-services, grand-central-dispatch

I want to do a web service call on a separate thread. I am using the below code,

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // My web service request goes from here 
});
```

The request goes successfully, however there is no response coming back, I am not able to figure out why.

If I use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // My Web service request goes from here 
});
```

Response is coming back but UI is blocked till then, I want to do the web service request in a separate thread without blocking the UI.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using `NSURLConnection`'s `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler`?  That would take care of sending the request on a background thread, and then you could do what you need in the `completionHandler`. Or better yet, you could use `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a background thread for the request, but handle the result (which changes UI) on the main.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905192/iphone-grand-central-dispatch-main-thread) shows how (basically by nesting your main queue block inside your background block), but there's a simpler way provided by NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http..."]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    // update the UI here
}];
```

This handy method performs the request off the main, and -- since you pass it the main queue -- performs the completion block on the main.

Comment: I understand, however my question is why is that if i run from a globalqueue or detach new thread my response is not coming back.