# What happens if dispatch on same queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'd like to understand for below case if it's needed to check whether callbackQueue is current queue.

Please help me clear these scenarios, about what could happen if current queue is callback queue:

1. callbackQueue is **main** queue.
2. callbackQueue is **concurrent** queue.
3. callbackQueue is **serial** queue.

```
- (void)fetchWithCallbackQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)callbackQueue
{
  dispatch_async(callbackQueue, ^{

  });
}
```

Comment: They are all fine with `dispatch_async`. The new block gets added to the end of the queue. No check needed. Though things may get trickier if you start adding semaphores or dispatch groups. So more details are needed to know for sure if there is a problem or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I highly recommend you to watch these videos. Then go through the examples I provided and then change the code and play around with them as much as you can.** It took me 3 years to feel fully comfortable with iOS multi-threading so take your time :D

Watch the first 3 minutes of [this RWDevCon video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxOrFvz0RXw) and more if you like.

Also watch [3:45](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=225) until [6:15](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=315). Though I recommend you watch this video in its entirety.

---

To summarize the points the videos make in the duration I mentioned:

threading and conccurrency is all about the **source** queue and **destination**. queue.

sync vs. async is specifically a matter of the source queue.

Think of source and destination queues of a highway where your work is being done.

If you do **async**, then it's like you sending a car (has to deliver stuff)  exiting the highway and then continue to let other cars drive in the highway.

If you do **sync**, then it's like you sending a car (has to deliver stuff) exiting the highway and then halting all other cars on the highway until the car delivers all its stuff.

Think of a car delivering stuff as a block of code, starting and finishing execution.

---

What happens for main queue is identical to what happens for serial queue. They're both serial queues.

So if you're already on main thread and dispatch to main thread and dispatch asynchronously then, anything you dispatch will **go to the end of the queue**

To show you what I mean: In what order do you think this would print? You can easily test this in Playground:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("1")
    print("2")
    print("3")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("4")
        }
        print("5")
        print("6")
        print("7")
    }
    print("8")
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("9")
    print("10")
}
```

It will print:

```
1
2
3
8
9
10
5
6
7
4
```

Why?

It's mainly because every time you dispatch to main from main, the block will be placed at the end of the main queue.

Dispatching to main while you're already on the main queue is very hidden subtle reason for **many tiny delays** that you see in an app's user-interaction.

---

What happens if you dispatch to the same **serial** queue using **sync**?

Deadlock! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424446/5175709)

If you dispatch to the same **concurrent** queue using **sync**, then you won't have a deadlock. But every other thread would just wait the moment you do **sync**. I've discussed that below.

---

Now if you're trying to dispatch to a concurrent queue, then if you do **sync**, it's just like the example of the highway, where the entire 5 lane highway is blocked till the car delivers everything. But it's kinda useless to do sync on a concurrent queue, unless you're doing something like a [`.barrier`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784770/5175709) queue and are trying to solve a [read-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) problem.

But to just see what happens if you do sync on a concurrent queue:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "aConcurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

for i in 0...4 {
    if i == 3 {
        queue.sync {
            someOperation(iteration: UInt32(i))
        }
    } else {
        queue.async {
            someOperation(iteration: UInt32(i))
        }
    }
}

func someOperation(iteration: UInt32) {
    sleep(1)
    print("iteration", iteration)
}
```

will log:

'3' will USUALLY (not always) be first (or closer to the first), because `sync` blocks get executed on the source queue. As [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync) on `sync` say:

> As a performance optimization, this function executes blocks on the current thread whenever possible

The other iterations happen concurrently. Each time you run the app, the sequence may be different. That's the inherit unpredictability associated with concurrency. 4 will be closer to being completed last and 0 would be closer to being finished sooner. So something like this:

```
iteration 3     
iteration 0
iteration 2
iteration 1
iteration 4
```

If you do **async** on a concurrent queue, then assuming you have a limited number of concurrent threads, e.g. 5 then 5 tasks would get executed at once. Just that each given task is going to the end of the queue. It would make sense to do this for logging stuff. You can have multiple log threads. One thread logging location events, another logging purchases, etc.

A good playground example would be:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial", attributes: .concurrent)

func delay(seconds: UInt32 ) {
    queue.async {
        sleep(seconds)
        print(seconds)
    }
}

for i in (1...5).reversed() {
    delay(seconds: UInt32(i))
}
```

Even though you've dispatched the 5 first, this would print

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your time very much for writing so many details with examples!

Comment: Happy to help. Shout out to Rob (he wrote the other answer here). I learned a lot of threading related stuff from him. To repeat myself, the best way to learn is to open a playground. Start with some form of threading you understand and then play with it and try figuring out things you don’t understand. Your question was a bit broad and lacked code. A better question would have been one where you have written code for a single scenario e.g. dispatch asnyc on same thread and then you showing us the result of the prints. You can do that right? But then ask us potential unknowns of how it works.

Comment: I also just made an edit and added code for dispatching synchronously on a concurrent queue

Answer (score 1):

In your example with `dispatch_async` (or just `async` in Swift), it doesn’t matter. The dispatched block will simply be added to the end of the relevant queue and will run asynchronously whenever that queue becomes available.

If, however, you used [`dispatch_sync`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452870-dispatch_sync?language=occ) (aka `sync` in Swift), then suddenly problems are introduced if you dispatch from a serial queue back to itself. With a “synchronous” dispatch from a serial queue to itself, the code will will “deadlock”. (And because the main queue is a serial queue, synchronous dispatches from main queue to itself manifest the same problem.) The `dispatch_sync` says “block the current thread until the designated queue finishes running this dispatched code”, so obviously if any serial queue dispatches synchronously back to itself, it cannot proceed because it’s blocking the queue to which you’ve dispatched the code to run.

Note that any blocking GCD API, such as [`dispatch_semaphore_wait`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1453087-dispatch_semaphore_wait?language=occ) and [`dispatch_group_wait`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452794-dispatch_group_wait?language=occ) (both known as simply `wait` in Swift), will suffer this same problem as the synchronous dispatch if you wait on the same thread that the serial queue uses.

But, in your case, dispatching *asynchronously* with `dispatch_async`, you shouldn’t have any problems.