# What's the difference between async and sync in swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

In this example, what's the difference between `queue.sync` and `queue.async`

```
var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "sample", qos: .background)

queue.sync {
   //some code
}
queue.async {
   //some code 
}
```

Comment: See [What happens if dispatch on same queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600133/what-happens-if-dispatch-on-same-queue/58600994#58600994). It contains a lot more than what you ask...

Comment: Also see my comment on Mohsen's answer below. It my help you understanding things better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both snippets append a closure to the queue.

But there is one difference.

### Sync

Synch will wait for the closure to be executed before processing the next line.

So in this case, the `print("Hello")` is executed **always after** the closure.

```
queue.sync {
   //some code
}
print("Hello")
```

### Async

In this case the closure is added to the queue and then the next line is executed. So the `print("Hello")` could be executed before the closure.

```
queue.async {
   //some code
}
print("Hello")
```

Comment: Also, calling `sync` might lead to dealock (especially with `DispatchQueue.main`). That cannot happen with `async`.